# MySQL not in very slow

Tags: mysql, sql, select, notin

I hope somebody can help me. This is the SQL query:

```
SELECT * 
FROM pf_profilvisit 
WHERE u1 = '".$user."' 
   AND u2 NOT IN (
      SELECT empf FROM pf_mailbox WHERE abs = '".$user."'
   ) 
   AND u2 NOT IN (
      SELECT abs FROM pf_mailbox WHERE empf = '".$user."'
   ) 
ORDER BY id DESC);
```

How can I make it faster?

Comment: uses `exists` instead of `in`? use joins and proper indexes instead of subselects?

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT pf_profilvisit.* 
FROM pf_profilvisit
LEFT JOIN  pf_mailbox 
ON pf_profilvisit.u2 = pf_mailbox.empf 
  OR pf_profilvisit.u2 = pf_mailbox.abs
WHERE pf_profilvisit.u1 = '".$user."' 
  AND pf_mailbox.empf IS NULL
  AND pf_mailbox.abs IS NULL
ORDER BY pf_profilvisit.id DESC;
```

Could you show your tables schema? Do you have columns `pf_mailbo.abs, pf_mailbo.empf, pf_profilvisit .u1, pf_profilvisit.u2, pf_profilvisit.id` indexed ?

Comment: Don't understand your question. What shell do you use to communicate with database? phpMyAdmin? MySQL workbench? I need to see `CREATE TABLE` statement for both tables

Comment: So go to the SQL tab and run command: `SHOW CREATE TABLE pf_profilvisit` and post here the output, and after repeat the same for `pf_mailbox`

Comment: Hello, i have fixed it by clicking "add index" on the row. it was now very very fast!!! :) thank you alex!!

Comment: This seems a very sensible alternative to OP's current solution. Please consider getting rid of questions in your answer. (What you are asking about indices could be rephrased in the form of a suggestion.)